# Inequality involving kernel matrix and quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, quadratic-forms, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Given data points $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and kernel $k(.,.): \mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n \to [0,1]$ which satisfies Mercer's theorem, construct the kernel matrix $A$ as $A_{ij} = k(x_i,x_j)$. Also apply the kernel to the data point $x_{n+1}$ and previous data points $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$, yielding the vector $b$ as $b_i = k(x_{n+1} ,x_i)$. Now consider the following quadratic form: $$q=b^TA^{-1}b$$ I want to find an upper bound on $q$. By simulation, I've found that $$q\le b^Tb\frac{1}{k(x,x)}$$ holds for many data points and kernels but I couldn't show that formally. Is it possible to prove that inequality? Note that it's assumed that the kernel is stationary and monotone which means $k(x,y)$ is a decreasing function of distance between $x$ and $y$: $$k(x,y) = f(\|x-y\|)$$

Comment: But who is $x?$

Comment: @GérardLetac It's assumed that kernel is a function of distance, so $f(x,x) = f(0,0)$.

Comment: So you mean that there exists $f$ such that $k(x_i,x_j)= f(\|x_i-x_j\|).$ Am I correct?

Comment: @GérardLetac Yes that's correct and $f$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

Since $k(x,y)=f(\|x-y\|)$ and since $A=f(\|x_i-x_j\|)_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$ and $A_1=f(\|x_i-x_j\|)_{1\leq i,j\leq n+1}$ are positive definite, their determinants are positive. Therefore by the Schur decomposition
$$A_1=\left[\begin{array}{cc}A&b\\b^T&f(0)\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}I_n&0\\b^TA^{-1}&1\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}A&0\\0&f(0)-q\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}I_n&A^{-1 }b\\0&1\end{array}\right]$$
we claim that $\det A_1=\det A(f(0)-q),$ which implies $q\leq f(0).$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's a valid upper bound but I'm looking for whether my proposed upper bound is correct.

Comment: I have doubts about the correctness of  $f(0)q\leq \|b\|^2.$ For instance if we want to use $q<f(0)$ and if we are trying to prove $f(0)^2<\|b\|^2$ from it, it is easy to design cases where $f(0)^2>\|b\|^2.$ But if your simulations indicate $f(0)q\leq \|b\|^2$ I will think about it a little bit more.

Comment: Assume $f(0)=1$ without loss of generality and apply the Schur decomposition to $X^TA_1X>0$ with $X^T=(-\lambda b,1)$ and  $ \lambda=1/\sqrt{b^TAb}$. I obtain $$\|b^2\|+q\leq 2\sqrt{b^TAb}$$

Comment: Thanks. Would you show your computations, please? I think by $\|b^2\|$ you mean $\|b\|^2$.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake and this last calculation gives only $\|b\|^2<\sqrt{b^TAb}.$

Comment: No problem. It would be great if you share any other ideas.